# I need to use aws_session_token with puppetlabs-aws

Tags: puppetlabs-aws

At my work, when using aws cli we use aws_session_token.  I don't see anything in puppetlabs-aws support for aws_session_token.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AWS_SESSION_TOKEN is usually used when you're obtaining temporary credentials from AWS security token service (STS). This is usually when you make the call to Assume a role. So a lot of this depends on how you've got your command line set up:

If you are explcitly calling assume role like this:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/RoleToAssume" --role-session-name AWSCLI-Session
```

You should get back a response with three variables:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
```

You should just be able to export each of these as environment variables and then run `puppet apply`.

If you are not explicitly calling assume role and are using instance profiles, puppet should automatically find these 3 variables.

If you are calling assume role via AWS_PROFILES in your `~/.aws/config` then it should just be sufficient to run `puppet apply` after setting the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable.

You may also want to consider using the [newer](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/amazon_aws) puppetlabs amazon_aws module which superseeds puppetlabs/aws.